# field label can not be hidden in drupal

Tags: drupal-7, field

I use the bartik theme in drupal7 as the default theme.And I completely override the page.tpl.php file.
design a two columns layout : the lefsidebar and the contentArea. Everything is ok except one problem.

the node's field label can not be set in the Manage display panel. And the node's body label was disappeared,and other's labels do exist but can not ,say, be set hidden ,above,inline.

I google the for solutions but bad luck no result.

Need your Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get the point in modifying the php file to do what you want. I think you just want to set a two-column layout, but you do not need to edit your code to do so. Have you tried the Display Suite module?

Comment: actually,I overrode the page.tpl.php just for design purpose.I didn't want to use extra modules.